# Combine two arrays with just matching override

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

The original:

```
array(2) {
  'app_name' =>
  string(15) "dropcat-default"
  'site' =>
  array(1) {
    'environment' =>
    array(7) {
      'drush_alias' =>
      NULL
      'backup_path' =>
      string(6) "backup"
      'config_name' =>
      NULL
      'original_path' =>
      string(33) "/var/www/webroot/shared/some_path"
      'symlink' =>
      string(43) "/var/www/webroot/mysite_latest/symlink_path"
      'url' =>
      string(17) "http://localhost"
      'name' =>
      string(11) "mystagesite"
    }
  }
}
```

And the one with overrides:

```
array(2) {
  'app_name' =>
  string(17) "dropcat-overrides"
  'site' =>
  array(1) {
    'environment' =>
    array(1) {
      'drush_alias' =>
      string(6) "foobar"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to replace the overrides in the original array, but keep the keys that are not present in the override - using `array_replace` just writes over the existing ones, because I have arrays in arrays. Is there a simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function _merge_array_rec($arr, $arr2, $i = 0)
{ 
    foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!isset($arr[$key]))
        {
            $arr[$key] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                $arr[$key] = _merge_array_rec($arr[$key], $arr2[$key], $i + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                $arr[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }        
    return $arr;
}

$merge_array = _merge_array_rec($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I also just discovered that there a function call `array_replace_recursive` - that also does what I am after.

Comment: @MikkeSchirén indeed! You can answer yourself and vote your best answer ;)

Comment: In array_replace_recursive function , values are not replace by second array. so i have to create function that override the values of first array

Answer (score 0):

[array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) gets it done for multi dimensional arrays.

As for single dimension arrays, looping through the original array then checking if the overriding array has this value is fun enough.

Something similar to this :

```
$original=array();
$overriding=array();
foreach($original as $key => $value){
  if(isset($overriding[$key]) && !empty($overriding[$key])){
      $original[$key]=$overriding[$key];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

- `array_key_exists` should be used instead of `isset`, because `isset` ignores `NULL`.
- The structure of `$overrides` should be validated, shouldn't it?

Try it out.

```
<?php

function array_replace_recursive_if_valid(array $defaults, array $overrides) {
    foreach ($overrides as $key => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $defaults)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (is_array($defaults[$key]) && is_array($value)) {
            $defaults[$key] = array_replace_recursive_if_valid($defaults[$key], $value);
            continue;
        }
        if (!is_array($defaults[$key]) && !is_array($value)) {
            $defaults[$key] = $value;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $defaults;
}

$defaults = [
    'app_name' => 'dropcat-default',
    'site' => [
        'environment' => [
            'drush_alias' => null,
            'back_path' => 'packup',
            'config_name' => null,
            'original_path' => '/var/www/webroot/shared/some_path',
            'symlink' => '/var/www/webroot/mysite_latest/symlink_path',
            'url' => 'http://localhost',
            'name' => 'mystagesite',
        ],
    ],
];

$overrides = [
    'app_name' => 'dropcat-overrides',
    'this is invalid' => 'foo',
    'site' => [
        'environment' => [
            'drush_alias' => 'foobar',
            'url' => ['this is invalid'],
        ],
    ],
];

var_export(array_replace_recursive_if_valid($defaults, $overrides));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended up doing it like this:

```
$configs = array_replace_recursive($default_config, $env_config);
```

It covered my use case.